# setting variables in javascript in jasp from ini file

Tags: javascript, spring-mvc

In my spring mvc project i have a properties.property file whose structure is as such

```
TestOrderURL=blah
LiveOrderURL=blah1
```

These values are used in my controller and are read using the @Value annotation.

The view [.jsp] has a javascript function which has variables that need to have their default value set from the above properties file. Is there a way to set this?

My HomeController.java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) 
{
    logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());
    return "Home";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set your variables from  controller to some specific scope i.e [HttpSession](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) so that you could access them in your javascript via [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html) or [Scriptlet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html).

**UPDATE:**

In your controller call:

```
request.getSession(false).setAttribute("YourProperty",propertyvalue);
```

then in javascript access them like:

```
var property=<%=session.getAttribute("YourProperty")%>;
```

**UPDATE:**
Change your controller method to this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/Home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String home(Locale locale, Model model,HttpServletRequest request) 
{
    request.getSession(false).setAttribute("YourProperty",propertyvalue);
    logger.info("Welcome home! the client locale is "+ locale.toString());
    return "Home";
}
```

or you could set in Your `model` also.

Comment: @Danglish Piyush: Any example links would be much appreciated

Comment: Many Thanks for the info. I updated my ? to show my code in the controller, there is no input param of HttpRequest type

Comment: I did try that before posting as that returns threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException]

Comment: model.AddAttributes does not throw error however I get no data with ${YourProperty}

Comment: @Piyush Dangling: I checked the code and error was on my end. In the EL I had a ; which was causing the issue and also the js code was looking for property var to be a string with quotes. No intention of being spoon fed. But many thanks